Popularity Trends and usage Data show 0 result - SharePoint 2019
Two months ago, we updated the passwords for all our service accounts in SharePoint 2019. Since then, everything has been running smoothly, including search functionality. However, today we noticed that the popularity trends usage reports are showing zero results for the past two months.
We checked following things:

Search is actively crawling the content.
Both SharePoint usage data import and processing timer jobs running on schedule.
Both Event Receivers are enable

Any ideas or assistance with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Is there any other ideas or assistance with this issue?
